# String interpolation warning in DispatchQueue closure

Tags: ios, swift, string-interpolation

Say I get below code, and it works fine.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // 1. put loadLevel() in background queue
    DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
      self?.loadLevel()
    }
  }

  func loadLevel() {
    var clueString = ""
    var solutionString = ""
    var letterBits = [String]()

    // 2. some heavy code here

    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
      // 3. push some UI code back to main thread
    }
```

However, when I move the background queue to inside loadLevel() and cover the heavy code and UI code, I get an issue that UI is updated with empty values when launching the app. So what is the different of this two ways?

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // 1. call loadLevel
    loadLevel()
  }

  func loadLevel() {
    var clueString = ""
    var solutionString = ""
    var letterBits = [String]()

    DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
      // 2. some heavy code in background queue

      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // 3. push UI code back to main thread
      }
    }
  }
```

### Update the 2nd code with the heavy code inside.

I found the issue, it is not related with GCD actually. This issue is in line `Bundle.main.url(forResource: "level\(self?.level)"`, which produces a String interpolation warning. And result resource load get `nil` I guess.

As I used weak reference [weak self] as capture list here, I need to put `self?` before the global variable `level` in case to use it in closure. If I give it a default value like `\(self?.level ?? 0)`, then this issue is fixed.

But is it that the property way to deal with this String interpolation here? Or some better approach should be involved here?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      
      // 1. call loadLevel
      loadLevel()
    }

    func loadLevel() {
      var clueString = ""
      var solutionString = ""
      var letterBits = [String]()

      DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
        if let levelFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "level\(self?.level)", withExtension: "txt") {
            if let levelContents = try? String(contentsOf: levelFileURL) {
                var lines = levelContents.components(separatedBy: "\n")
                lines.shuffle()
                self?.correctGuess = 0
                print("AAA")
                
                for (index, line) in lines.enumerated() {
                    let parts = line.components(separatedBy: ": ")
                    let answer = parts[0]
                    let clue = parts[1]
                    
                    clueString += "\(index + 1). \(clue)\n"
                    
                    let solutionWord = answer.replacingOccurrences(of: "|", with: "")
                    solutionString += "\(solutionWord.count) letters\n"
                    self?.solutions.append(solutionWord)
                    
                    let bits = answer.components(separatedBy: "|")
                    letterBits += bits
                    print("ABC")
                }
            }
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          // 3. push UI code back to main thread
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: There is probably no reason to use weak self here anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a reference to:

```
let resource = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "level\(self?.level)" withExtension: ...)
```

The warning is

> String interpolation produces a debug description for an optional value; did you mean to make this explicit?

The compiler is warning you that you are performing string interpolation of an optional value.

Let's consider a simpler example, to show what happens when you do string interpolation with optionals:

```
print("\(self?.level)")
```

If level was `xxx`, it would print

> Optional("xxx")

And obviously if `self` or `level` were optional, it would just say:

> `nil`

Clearly, neither of these are quite what you want. So, unwrap the optional. E.g.

```
guard let level = self?.level else { return }

let resource = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "level\(level)" withExtension: ...)
```

Comment: Great solution, as I was using capture list [weak self] here, `self` would be optional, so say self?.level. So unwrap its optional chain would make thing clear here. And I'm curious about why only string interpolation get complained, there is other things here call `self?.xxx`.

Comment: Setting `self?.xxx = "foo"` does nothing, as does `self?.yyy()`, so there’s no worries with either of those. That having been said, we sometimes do a `guard let self = self else { return }` just to get rid of all of the `self?` references...

Answer (score 0):

Let me start off by saying, I have no idea, but I have an idea for you to test. Move `DispatchQueue.global().async` to the first line of `loadLevel()`.

```
func loadLevel() {
  DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
    var clueString = ""
    var solutionString = ""
    var letterBits = [String]()

    // 2. some heavy code in background queue

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      // 3. push UI code back to main thread
    }
  }
}
```

This isolates the change to just calling `loadLevel()`. If this works as expected, then keep moving the `DispatchQueue.global().async` call down until it does break.

```
func loadLevel() {
  var clueString = ""

  DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
    var solutionString = ""
    var letterBits = [String]()

    // 2. some heavy code in background queue

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      // 3. push UI code back to main thread
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: To include the variables declaration, I did that but no help. But it is a good idea, I have created a small project to test this to see what is the root cause.

Comment: I found the issue, which related with String interpolation but not GCD. Please see my update in answer.